# python now, next, n iteration

Tags: python, function, iterator

writing a general function that can iterate over any iterable returning now, next pairs.

```
def now_nxt(iterable):
    iterator = iter(iterable)
    nxt = iterator.__next__()
    for x in iterator:
        now = nxt
        nxt = x
        yield (now,nxt) 

for i in now_nxt("hello world"):
    print(i)

('h', 'e')
('e', 'l')
('l', 'l')
('l', 'o')
('o', ' ')
(' ', 'w')
('w', 'o')
('o', 'r')
('r', 'l')
('l', 'd')
```

I have been thinking about the best way to write a function where the number of items in each tuple can be set.

for example if it was

```
func("hello",n=3)
```

the result would be:

```
('h','e','l')
('e','l','l')
('l','l','o')
```

I am new to using timeit, so please point out if I doing anything wrong here:

```
import timeit

def n1(iterable, n=1):
    #now_nxt_deque
    from collections import deque
    deq = deque(maxlen=n)
    for i in iterable:
        deq.append(i)
        if len(deq) == n:
            yield tuple(deq)

def n2(sequence, n=2):
    # now_next
    from itertools import tee
    iterators = tee(iter(sequence), n)
    for i, iterator in enumerate(iterators):
        for j in range(i):
            iterator.__next__()
    return zip(*iterators)

def n3(gen, n=2):
    from itertools import tee, islice
    gens = tee(gen, n)
    gens = list(gens)
    for i, gen in enumerate(gens):
        gens[i] = islice(gens[i], i, None) 
    return zip(*gens)


def prin(func):
    for x in func:
        yield x

string = "Lorem ipsum tellivizzle for sure ghetto, consectetuer adipiscing elit."

print("func 1: %f" %timeit.Timer("prin(n1(string, 5))", "from __main__ import n1, string, prin").timeit(100000))
print("func 2: %f" %timeit.Timer("prin(n2(string, 5))", "from __main__ import n2, string, prin").timeit(100000))
print("func 3: %f" %timeit.Timer("prin(n3(string, 5))", "from __main__ import n3, string, prin").timeit(100000))
```

results:

```
$  py time_this_function.py 
func 1: 0.163129
func 2: 2.383288
func 3: 1.908363
```

Comment: Looks good to me.  I might try out getting rid of the len() check by having two loops: one to prime the deque with the first n-1 items, and then a loop to yield full tuples.  But I also might decide it was better with just one loop.

Comment: You might want to consider just asking the question "how to do this", and then posting your thing as an answer, rather than putting it in the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My proposal would be,

```
from collections import deque

def now_nxt_deque(iterable, n=1):
    deq = deque(maxlen=n)
    for i in iterable:
        deq.append(i)
        if len(deq) == n:
            yield tuple(deq)

for i in now_nxt_deque("hello world", 3):
    print(i)

('h', 'e', 'l')
('e', 'l', 'l')
('l', 'l', 'o')
('l', 'o', ' ')
('o', ' ', 'w')
(' ', 'w', 'o')
('w', 'o', 'r')
('o', 'r', 'l')
('r', 'l', 'd')
```

Answer (score 5):

Here's a really simple way to do it:

- Clone your iterator `n` times using using [`itertools.tee`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.tee)
- Advance the `i`th iterator `i` times
- `izip` them all together

```
import itertools

def now_next(sequence, n=2):
    iterators = itertools.tee(iter(sequence), n)
    for i, iterator in enumerate(iterators):
        for j in range(i):
            iterator.next()
    return itertools.izip(*iterators)
```

Comment: Great solution! Just one thought: Since you've started with iterators, maybe it would make sense to stick with that pattern and `return itertools.izip(*iterators)` at the end?

Comment: @jathanism: good point. I just wend with `zip` for clarity. Edited.

Comment: @Eric, how scalable would this method be? is there much of a cost involved with cloning iterators?

Comment: @ThemanontheClaphamomnibus: Not sure. Cloning iterators is better than cloning the collection! Not sure my solution would do any better than yours.

Comment: Instead of `iterator.next()` you should do `next(iterator)`.

Comment: @dav1d `next(iterator)` does make it a tiny bit faster.

Answer (score 2):

My solution:

```
def nn(itr, n):
    iterable = iter(itr)

    last = tuple(next(iterable, None) for _ in xrange(n))
    yield last
    for _ in xrange(len(itr)):
        last = tuple(chain(last[1:], [next(iterable)]))
        yield last
```

This was made for Python 2, if you wanna use it with Python 3, replace `xrange` with `range`.

`next`, has a great `default` parameter, which will be returned instead of raising a `StopIteration`, you could also add this default-parameter to your function like so:

```
def nn(itr, n, default=None):
    iterable = iter(itr)

    last = tuple(next(iterable, default) for _ in xrange(n))
    yield last
    for _ in xrange(len(itr)):
        last = tuple(chain(last[1:], [next(iterable, default)]))
        yield last
```

I played some more with it, e.g. using `itr.__class__()` as default, but that seems wrong for lists and tuples, well it just makes sense for strings.

Comment: This is definitely a compact solution.

Comment: `len(itr)` doesn't work for generators which makes this less general purpose.

Comment: You're right, so I tried to find a better way and I remembered the itertools documentation, I edited the post.

Comment: OP wants overlapping subsequences, not what `grouper` produces.

Comment: Correct, I removed that, my bad.

Comment: @dav1d is there any way to not have `None` in the tuples at the end?

Comment: Yes, use my sencond example, the default parameter changes that

Answer (score 1):

A variation on Eric's technique that uses slicing

```
from itertools import tee, islice, izip

def now_next(gen, n=2):
  gens = tee(gen, n)
  gens = list(gens)
  for i, gen in enumerate(gens):
    gens[i] = islice(gens[i], i, None) 
  return izip(*gens)

for x in now_next((1,2,3,4,5,6,7)):
  print x
```

Comment: this appears to be faster than Erics, I have added the function to the timeit list in the question. - note that as I am using Python 3.X, izip is now zip

Answer (score 0):

A one-liner based on cravoori's answer:

```
from itertools import tee, islice, izip

def now_next(gen, n=2):
    return izip(*(islice(g, i, None) for i, g in enumerate(tee(gen, n))))
```